# Converted value from String to integer cannot be entered in JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, numberformatexception

I am trying to convert the roll no that is accepted in a JTextField into an integer value so that it can be used in MySQL but whenever i hit the commit button, an error pops up saying

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at random.student$1.actionPerformed(student.java:141)
```

This is the code that i have used

```
package random;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class student extends JFrame{

    int N = 0;
    int i,j;        // instance variables

    String namex[] = new String[10];                // used in jdbc
    String course[] = new String[10];
    int roll_no[] = new int[10];

    // jdbc

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;

    public student() {

        super("Student");
        setLayout(null);                    // when layout is null, setBounds method is used with every window component to set the location and dimensions of every object

        String no = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the number of students");               // data is accepted in form of String
        N = Integer.parseInt(no);               // changes string to integer

        JLabel lbl[] = new JLabel[N];
        JLabel top[] = new JLabel[4];
        JTextField name[] = new JTextField[N];              // Name
        JTextField crse[] = new JTextField[N];              // Course
        JTextField roll[] = new JTextField[N];              // roll no



        // title bar

        top[0] = new JLabel("SNo");
        top[0].setBounds(200,8,50,30);
        add(top[0]);

        top[1] = new JLabel("Name");
        top[1].setBounds(250,8,50,30);
        add(top[1]);


        top[2] = new JLabel("Roll No");
        top[2].setBounds(380,8,50,20);
        add(top[2]);

        top[3] = new JLabel("Course");
        top[3].setBounds(450,8,50,20);
        add(top[3]);


        // SNo
        for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {

            lbl[i] = new JLabel((i+1)+"");
            lbl[i].setBounds(200, j+30, 50, 30);
            add(lbl[i]);

            j = j + 30;             // height component
        }

        // Name fields
        j = 0;
        for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {

            name[i] = new JTextField(30);
            name[i].setBounds(250, j+30, 100, 20);
            add(name[i]);

            j = j + 30;
        }


        // roll no

        j = 0;

        for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {

            roll[i] = new JTextField(10);
            roll[i].setBounds(380,j+30,50,20);
            add(roll[i]);

            j = j + 30;
        }

        // course

        j = 0 ; 

        for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {

            crse[i] = new JTextField(20);
            crse[i].setBounds(450, j + 30, 50, 20);
            add(crse[i]);

            j+= 30;
        }

        JButton btn = new JButton("Commit");
        btn.setBounds(400,300,100,40);
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent exp) {

                try {

                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student","root",".dpadpep");

                    String sql = "Insert into student(roll_no,name,course) values(?,?,?)";

                    // Convert JTextField into String and integers

                    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


                    for(i = 0 ; i < N ; i++) {


                        namex[i] = name[i].getText();           // convert TextField to String
                        course[i] = crse[i].getText();

                        String text = roll[i].getText();
                        int rollno = Integer.parseInt(text);            // first convert TextFIeld yo string and then into integer

                        stmt.setInt(1, rollno);
                        stmt.setString(2, namex[i]);
                        stmt.setString(3, course[i]);

                    }


                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        });


        setLocation(100, 100);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600,450);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new student();
    }

}
```

I edited this code in something different. The table is updated but error also pops up whenever i hit commit.
Please Help.

I cannot convert the String value in textfield to integer value. I have done it before when the TextField were not an array but they were working individually.

Comment: I'd recommend you have a look at [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for a better way of managing user input. The error message is also telling you everything you need to know, you need to debug the code and figure out why it's happening and devise a strategy for solving it

Answer (score 0):

This is because when no string(You typed nothing and pressed commit) is given java cannot translate that text to an integer (Imagine having to translate nothing/some jibberish to an int), that's why the error says

> For input string: ""
>    )

What you can do is set a default value for the Roll No field like 0. Next, validate the input for Roll No so that, only numbers can be inserted into the Roll No text field.

hope this helps.